# Golang: cast interface back to its original type

Tags: go, reflection

I couldn't really find an answer to this, even though I looked up the Go documentation and examples. Is it possible to cast an interface back to its original type, dynamically? I know I can do something like this:

```
var myint int = 5
var myinterface interface{}
myinterface = myint
recovered, _ := myinterface.(int)
fmt.Println(recovered)
```

But here I know the type. I would like to have a map of unknown types (interfaces) and cast them back by using reflection, like this:

```
// put/pop writes/read to/from a map[string]interface{}
var myint int = 5
put("key" myint)
pop("key", &myint) // this should also work for objects or any other type
```

Like this it would by possible to store anything within a single map. The type will be handed in by the user when calling pop() (second argument is an interface). Is it possible to achive this using reflection?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't assert a type from an interface without knowing what that type is at compile time, but you can set a value from an interface via reflection. Here's an example without any error checks, which panics when any parameters don't match:

```
var m = map[string]interface{}{}

func put(k string, v interface{}) {
    m[k] = v
}

func pop(k string, o interface{}) {
    reflect.ValueOf(o).Elem().Set(reflect.ValueOf(m[k]))
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/ORcKhtU_3O

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you :)